# Add a custom field from InventoryItem DAC to Acumatica Customer Portal>Catalog screen

Tags: acumatica

I created a new custom field usrManufSku in Stock Item screen in ERP.  And would like to create a new customization in the portal to bring this new field in the Catalog screen.  I was hoping that the new custom field would just be inherited and can bring into the grid easily but it's not. I don't know how to reference it.  It keeps saying it doens't exist in InventoryItem nor InventoryItemExt.  How do I add this field to InventoryLines DAC? Please help!

Comment: The customer portal is technically a separate website, so you need to add the DAC extension to it too. Even though the field is in the database, the portal is not aware of any customizations done to the ERP website.

Comment: I got it working. Thanks. I had to add a custom field not the same name as the original custom field and call out the full path PX.Objects.IN.InventoryItemExt.usrManufSku. it didn't like just the dac name.